# $inc operator not working in my flask app using mongodb atlas

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm looking to increment the 'views' field by +1 in my document within my collection. I'm using mongodb atlas database to be included in my flask app. I've included my route here. Any suggestions would be great thanks.

```
@app.route('/view_count/<recipe_id>', methods=['POST'])
def view_count(recipe_id):
    mongo.db.recipes.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(recipe_id)}, {"$inc": {'views': 1}})
    return redirect(url_for('view_recipe.html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you queries are correct if you are using pymongo.
maybe, the problem are mongo.db.

Example

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient
# connect to general db
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')

# mongo accept everything, so is ok these queries below
# OBS: client.db means connection with database called db inside mongo
client.db.recipes.insert_one({'_id':ObjectId(), 'views': 0})
client.db.recipes.find_one({}) # the insertion above work
client.db.recipes.update_one({}, {'$inc': {'views': 1}}) # have only one, so update they
```

but if you change:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
# with
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017').db

# everything continue working, but now, the path to recipes is db.db.db.recipes
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using pymongo and I've tried everything you suggested but it's still not working on the 'like button' I keep gettting a "method not allowed" error.

Comment: you can add more details?